# Crash on download asynchronous images in iphone dev

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, asynchronous

I am using [this link](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/) for downloading asynchronously images and display them onto my table view and at the same time i use same asynchronous class onto my next view but when dealloc is called of last time used asynchronous class then my application is crash. Someone please help me on that, thanks in advance.

Comment: [Switching to thread 11523]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: What i think that i use this class onto two different classes so when you fast switch between these two classes on last class images are not being download yet and on same time its(asynchronous)dealoc is called.

Comment: Set environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES and debug.
 
   Your question without crash log or debug info looks like end user complaining that app crashed. Since you are a developer posting question on Stackoverflow we would expect you to provide us as much debug info possible. There are hundreds of questions related to EXC_BAD_ACCESS all of them lead to this answer setting NSZombieEnabled.

Answer (score 0):

You sent a method to a released object. You can find it out by yourself.
Please turn on malloc stack and zombie for your scheme in XCode:

> Product -> Edit Scheme -> Diagnostics
>   check 'Enable Zombie Objects' & 'Malloc Stack'

Then run the app, XCode should enter the debugger mode after crash. Run the command below at the console:

> info malloc 0x1234567

And you'll find which object cause this EXC_BAD_ACCESS in your console.